# Oracle not available offline

Tags: oracle

I recently faced a weird problem where I cannot use/log into any Oracle user nor even System account as well as not being able to access my database.
I have a Windows 10 64 bits Home edition, and I did multiple new installation of both Oracle XE 11g release 2 and Oracle XE 18c.
When I installed the XE 11g R2, and when trying to connect to SQLplus using the command line I get the following error
[image]

So searched for this error and I found that it is probably related to the database as it is not being mounted correctly everytime: 
I did the following:
[image]

Now I get the ORA-00119 & ORA00130 ERRORS, and I honeslty don't know where is the problem especially because all of these problems do not occur when I'm using an Internet Connexion using WIFI at home.
If anyone got any idea on how I can fix this please share!
Here are the following settings I currently have for Oracle:

**LSNRCTL status:**
[image]

**the C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\ADMIN\listner.ora**

> SID_LIST_LISTENER =
>     (SID_LIST =
>       (SID_DESC =
>         (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
>         (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
>         (PROGRAM = extproc)
>       )
>       (SID_DESC =
>         (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
>         (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
>         (PROGRAM = extproc)
>       )
>     )
>
> LISTENER =
>     (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
>       (DESCRIPTION =
>         (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
>         (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ASUS-AlexLutinNoir)(PORT = 1521))
>       )
>     )
>
> DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)

**the C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora **

> XE =
>     (DESCRIPTION =
>       (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ASUS-AlexLutinNoir)(PORT = 1521))
>       (CONNECT_DATA =
>         (SERVER = DEDICATED)
>         (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
>       )
>     )
>
> EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
>     (DESCRIPTION =
>       (ADDRESS_LIST =
>         (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
>       )
>       (CONNECT_DATA =
>         (SID = PLSExtProc)
>         (PRESENTATION = RO)
>       )
>     )

**The services that are running for oracle :**
[image]

**My envirement variables:**
[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
create pfile from spfile;
exit
```

Now edit `C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\database\initXE.ora`. Remove the line with `local_listener`, you use the default 1521 port on your local machine, you do not need that line. Once done:

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
create spfile from pfile;
startup
```

The problem is that your hostname is `ASUS-ALEXLUTINNOIR`, but only the first 15 characters was put in the `local_listener` parameter (`ASUS-ALEXLUTINN`).  The database can't resolve that hostname when starting up. In such a simple configuration you do not need the `local_listener` set, just leave it blank (remove), so the database will register itself to the listener running on the default port (1521).

Comment: Here is what I get from the create pfile from spfile; command:   ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01565: error in identifying file
'%ORACLE_HOME%\DATABASE\SPFILE%ORACLE_SID%.ORA'
ORA-27041: unable to open file
OSD-04002: unable to open file
O/S-Error: (OS 2) Le fichier sp┐cifi┐ est introuvable. ( means that the following file could not be found)

Comment: Sounds like environment variables weren't set.  For XE, this can be caused by not installing as an Administrator.   I prefer to "right click->run as administrator" for installation.

Comment: in the initXE.ORA file I only find the following line:SPFILE='C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\dbs/spfileXE.ora'

Comment: so previously the command didn't work, and when opening the initXE file I get a path to SPFILEXE to 'C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\dbs/spfileXE.ora I manually went to that directory and copy/paste the file into my C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\database I was able to execute the 1st block of the asnwer where it says: create pfile from spfile; now I have some content into my initXE.ora file but there is no local_listener line anywhere, only audit_file_dest, .compatible, .control_files,.db_name,DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST_SIZE,...

Answer (score 0):

So I solved my problem by:
1) changing my computer name so it fits the 15 15 characters.
2) Re-installing the Oracle XE11gR2 and running the setup as administrator (even tho' the pop up window would still ask for admin perm with or without the run as admin option).
3) Shutdown and startup mount were not followed with errors anymore and everything seems to be working, except that I still have no spfile in oracle_home\database.